# Python renaming duplicates

Tags: python, list, duplicates, rename

How to solve this renaming duplicates problem without resorting to renaming with something unique like `"_DUPLICATED_#NO"` the names have to be unique when finished, and preferably with iterative numbers denoting number of duplicates

```
from collections import defaultdict

l = ["hello1","hello2","hello3",
     "hello","hello","hello"]

tally = defaultdict(lambda:-1)
for i in range(len(l)):
    e = l[i]
    tally[e] += 1
    if tally[e] > 0:
        e += str(tally[e])
    l[i] = e
print (l)
```

results:

```
['hello1', 'hello2', 'hello3', 'hello', 'hello1', 'hello2']
```

as you can see, the names are not unique

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems simple enough. You start with a list of filenames:

```
l = ["hello1","hello2","hello3",
     "hello","hello","hello"]
```

Then you iterate through them to finished filenames, incrementing a trailing number by 1 if a duplicate is found.

```
result = {}
for fname in l:
    orig = fname
    i=1
    while fname in result:
        fname = orig + str(i)
        i += 1
    result[fname] = orig
```

This should leave you with a dictionary like:

```
{"hello1": "hello1",
 "hello2": "hello2",
 "hello3": "hello3",
 "hello": "hello",
 "hello4": "hello",
 "hello5": "hello"}
```

Of course if you don't care about mapping the originals to the duplicate names, you can drop that part.

```
result = set()
for fname in l:
    orig = fname
    i=1
    while fname in result:
        fname = orig + str(i)
        i += 1
    result.add(fname)
```

If you want a list afterward, just cast it that way.

```
final = list(result)
```

---

Note that if you're creating files, this is exactly what the `tempfile` module is designed to do.

```
import tempfile

l = ["hello1","hello2","hello3",
     "hello","hello","hello"]

fs = [tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(prefix=fname, delete=False, dir="/some/directory/") for fname in l]
```

This will not create nicely incrementing filenames, but they are guaranteed unique, and `fs` will be a list of the (open) file objects rather than a list of names, although `NamedTemporaryFile.name` will give you the filename.

Comment: @PRMoureu fixed. Whoops, algorithms are hard ;) This WILL turn `['hello1', 'hello1']` into `['hello1', 'hello11']`, but I can't think of a great way to generalize a solution that would produce `['hello1', 'hello2']` in a way that wouldn't break other less-obvious edge cases.

Comment: this is fine, well done, didn't think of using while >_<

Comment: @new_to_coding check out my edit if you're using this to create files.

Comment: Also `'hello1' > 'hello11'` is the right way i think, it will be weird to alter the input words, the goal is to avoid duplicates